# What movie has a sofa time machine and a flying bike?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I watched a movie in, I think, 2009 or 2010. I think it was from the 1990's or 2000’s.

It was a time travel movie. In this movie I think the time machine is fixed in a three-seater sofa, and three people including a woman are traveling in time. A person is following them on a flying bike to try to catch them. At one point they’re caught by soldiers, and a king orders them to be burned with their sofa, but they use it to escape again.

What movie is this?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: @GovindChoudhary: Can you provide more details, possibly by contrasting your movie against the two suggestions so far to indicate what is and is not there?

Comment: [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedknobs_and_Broomsticks) a film about time-travellers on a *bed* (not a sofa, but you did say "sofa bed" in the duplicate question), but no flying bike as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 14):

It is most likely the German spoof movie [*Traumschiff Surprise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traumschiff_Surprise_%E2%80%93_Periode_1).

It parodies a great number of sci-fi movies and TV shows, especially those popular in Germany.

The heroes, the Queen, the Captain of the *Surprise*, his Science Officer and  the Rogue (named Rock, a taxi driver) use a **sofa** in order to travel through time to prevent a planetary invasion in their own time. The sofa *does* indeed seat only three, which becomes a plotpoint, since they are overburdened and at first crash in the wrong time and are forced to leave one of their own behind in the end.

During their odyssey through history, The bad guy chases them on a **moped**:

[image: bad guy on moped]

Comment: I have to say that I am amazed that this would not be the one...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Me too, I mean, seriously, how many time-travelling sofas can there be ;D

Comment: I'm not sure that they using sofa as a time machine but in a scene all of three travellers caught by soldiers of a king and then king orders to burn them with their sofa. But when soldiers goes to burn them they were disappear I mean went to any other place by using their time machine. So I think that they using this sofa as time machine..

Comment: @GovindChoudhary That is actually their first stop, the king is *William the Last* and they vanish from the stakes (which is were the king had put the sofa with them on it, in order to burn them alive), because he wanted to marry the queen...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: maybe *Traumschiff Surprise* was re-made.

Comment: Definitely Traumshiff, the only other Time traveling sofa was Hitch Hikers guide to the Galaxy, at the end of the Tv series, they are stranded in prehistoric earth.., but the books go on further, Arthur and Ford escape on a time traveling Sofa, and end up on the Lords Cricket Ground in London. But it was never made in to a series.

Answer (score 3):

This is [Traumschiff Surprise – Periode 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traumschiff_Surprise_%E2%80%93_Periode_1), a german comedy and *Star Trek*/*Star Wars* spoof from 2004.

The Sofa is their time machine, the persons travelling are Captain Kork, Spuck, taxi driver Rock, and Queen Metapha. They land in medieval times and nearly get burned before they can reactivate their time machine.

They are chased by Jens Maul on his time machine hover bike.

Answer (score 1):

I'll look for more details, but is it possible that you're thinking of the 2005 independent film *[Fetching Cody](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1203528-fetching_cody/)*? The time machine is in a recliner, not a sofa, and it's just one guy traveling through time. And there's no flying bike... but that's the closest match I've found so far.

From the Rotten Tomatoes summary:

> A small-time Vancouver drug dealer traverses through time in a desperate bid to alter the grim fate of his comatose girlfriend in this bittersweet time travel fantasy from first-time director David Ray. Art (Jay Baruchel) is a petty drug slinger whose relationship with girlfriend and addict Cody (Sarah Lind) is starting to get serious. After Art arrives home one evening to find Cody overdosed on the floor and drifting into a coma, he seeks refuge at the home of eccentric junk collector Harvey (Jim Byrnes) -- an old street friend who claims that the ratty recliner he has recently acquired is actually a cleverly disguised time machine. Immediately dismissing his friend's outlandish claim but desperate to fulfill his promise that he will always be there to protect her, Art collapses in the chair and wishes himself back to the time before Cody became addicted to drugs. Upon awakening in another time, Art realizes that the chair is in fact the real deal and embarks on a desperate mission to change the future and save Cody's life.

Comment: Thanks Sir but I have been watched fetching Cody but that was different.

Answer (score -1):

[image] Dreamship Surprise - Period 1 Full Movie - YouTube

Comment: Did you mean to link to a specific link for the full movie?

Comment: It would help if you could describe why this answers the question.

Comment: This is the same answer as was given twice and rejected six months ago